# Javascript / заполнение массива

Tags: массивы, javascript

строка из формы -

```
<input type="text" name="stroka">
```

а в скрипт нужно значения строки поместит в массив. чтоб потом посчитать сумму Чисел строки. как посоветуете реализовать?

```
var arr = [];
for(var i=0,j=obj.stroka.(length-1);i<j;i++)
{ 
    arr[i]=obj.stroka.value.charAt[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var strk = document.getElementById("my-input").value, sum =0;
for(var i=0, max = strk.length;i<max;i++)
    if(!isNaN(strk.charAt(i))) sum += 1*strk.charAt(i);
alert(sum);
```

Этот код будет считать сумму только односимвольных цифр, входящих в строку, введенной в инпуте с id="my-input"